# Is there an Objective-C client for Cassandra?

Tags: objective-c, cassandra

I want to access a Cassandra instance in an Iphone application and i need an objectiveC client 
for that. I couldnt find one, Thrift is supposed to support ObjectiveC but I couldnt figure out how to do that. If anyone has any knowledge on the subject it is very much appriciated.

Answer (score 2):

Apache Thrift has a generator for ObjC. ([Complete list](http://wiki.apache.org/thrift/LibraryFeatures?action=show&redirect=LanguageSupport)).
If you will distribute the application I would considered the alternative to create a server with simple interface (eg. http) that in turns access the cassandra database. 
But if you are the only user it could work with direct database access.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not sure about how to get Thrift to generate the bindings then go with what Schildmeijer posted. Use a simple web server running php + phpcassa or any language of your choice that comes with a high level client library -- list here: [High level clients](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/ClientOptions).
You can use some open source libraries to expose resources from Cassandra as JSON or XML then use NSURLRequests to do the work. If you go with XML then Google's GDataXML is an excellent choice of parser, if you go with JSON then json-library on Google Code is another great choice.

Have fun!